# Why this ByteArray experiment crashes AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, adobe

I'm writing data into a new ByteArray and storing it into LocalStore

```
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
ba.writeObject(theobject);

EncryptedLocalStore.setItem(MY_VAL_STORE, ba); //bytes in local store
```

As an experiment, I'm trying to turn the 1st 2 lines into a single line, so I'm using this syntax (I basically put the new ByteArray in brackets and use it right away).

```
var ba:ByteArray = (new ByteArray).writeObject(theobject) as ByteArray;

EncryptedLocalStore.setItem(MY_VAL_STORE, ba); //bytes in local store
```

But this is making my AIR app crash at runtime. If I go back to the 2 lines, it works fine. I realize this isn't such a big deal, but I'm curious why this creative syntax isn't working. Any ideas?

**note:** in the 1-line version, if I don't add `as ByteArray`, it complains that I'm trying to use type void with ByteArray.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've answered your question yourself:

> it complains that I'm trying to use type void with ByteArray.

In your declaration, you assign the result of `writeObject()` to your ByteArray variable, not the instance created by `new ByteArray()`.  Since the result type is `void`, this assignment is illegal and causes the compiler to throw an error.  You've then added a manual cast of `void` to ByteArray, which obviously is enough to fool the compiler, but does not prevent a type cast error at runtime.

In short: This type of assignment works only if the methods called on the new instance return `this`.  A useful means to make code more readable, by the way, also known as the concept of [Method Chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So I guess I'm out of luck because `writeObject()` doesn't return `this`

Comment: Exactly. You could, of course, extend ByteArray and create your own `fromObject (obj:Object)` wrapper method (`writeObject( obj );` and `return this;`).  But unless you're using this more often, that wouldn't really be less lines of code. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation for the [writeObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#writeObject%28%29) call I guess that your code isn't working because the return value of the method is `void` and you try to cast it to an `ByteArray`.